# Replace sequence of bytes in binary file Java

Tags: java, binaryfiles, binary-data

Is there a way in Java to replace a sequence of bytes in a binary file?
I know there are the `write` methods in `RandomAccessFile`, but I'm looking for a way to replace the next N bytes in the file.

Edit: my understanding is that `write` will insert an array of bytes rather than replacing them.

For example:

Starting file: <byte0><byte1><byte2>...

What I want: <byte0><insertedByte><byte2>...

My understanding of how  `write` works: <byte0><insertedByte><byte1><byte2>

Comment: That's what the write method does. Can you explain what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: My understanding was that write inserts an array of bytes rather than replacing them. For example <byte0><byte1> would become <byte0><newByte><byte1> rather than <byte0><newByte>

Comment: Read the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html and you can write a small program to check.

Comment: I don't think your understanding is correct. The documentation says "If the random access file is created in read/write mode, then output operations are also available; output operations write bytes starting at the file pointer and advance the file pointer past the bytes written. Output operations that write past the current end of the implied array cause the array to be extended." This implies that output operations that do not write past the end will not change the size.